# Facebook Registration: Decoding the signed_request

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, .net-3.5

Can anyone point me in the direction of any tutorials that might be available to this.

Thus far I have only found one for framework 4 and MVC, which I am not even sure would work with framework 3.5.

I have found other references too difficult to understand as I am a novice to C#.

So far I have imported the facebook.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll.

I have got the signed request as detailed below but I don't know where to go from here

```
string requested_Data = Request.Form["signed_request"];
```

I think once I get this working, I may write a tutorial on here for all to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's sample code in PHP at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

It should be applicable to any language provided there's a HMAC-SHA256 implementation for it

Comment: Sorry I have no understanding of php :( hence I am really confused

Comment: Ah Cool, thanks to the help of stack over flow I was able to find all of the answers on here :)  Yippee